# My FancyBox ( Lightbox ) events are not firing off when rendered in my BB View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, fancybox

Not entirely sure why.. here is my render :

```
render: function() {

  var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
  $(this.el).html(html);

  $.fancybox( this.$el.html() );
```

The fancybox loads. But none of my otherwise working buttons are clickable. If I do not load it in a fancybox, and instead, pass an $el that is located on the DOM somewhere, then all the events and dynamic content is properly loaded.

How do I load this content into a FancyBox popup?

Comment: I think it's because you bound your events with the "events" property of your view, which basically makes a $(el).on('...', '...', func) but you're not passing your el to fancybox (only its content) so nothing is bound to your elements.

Comment: `this.$el.html()` is a string of HTML, strings of HTML don't have event handlers. `this.el` is a DOM element, DOM elements do have event handlers.

Comment: @muistooshort the problem with not converting it to a string, is that FancyBox will not load something unless its HTML.. I can't ( I don't believe ) pass a jQuery object into it.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to pass it as a content object in FancyBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass the element to fancybox, not just a string of HTML. Try this:

```
render: function() {
    var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(html);
    $.fancybox(this.$el);
}
```

Comment: This answer completely makes sense to me. However, it returns a FancyBox standard error saying that something went wrong.

Comment: Are you using the [latest version of fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox)? The [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for `$.fancybox.open` (which is the same as `$.fancybox()` suggest that using a jQuery object this way is valid.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. You have to pass the item as a `content` param, and it works fine. Thanks so much for your answer.